# How to get desired String from whole

Tags: iphone, nsstring

How to remove string from the original one

i.e. my string is,

```
series0001.0001
or
series0010.0101
or
series0110.0050
```

from this string I have to convert it to

```
expected result

Series 1 1
Series 10 101
Series 110 50
```

This is the code stuff which I am doing

```
    NSArray * words = [sym.data componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n\r\n"];
        NSLog(@"words are %@",words);
    NSString *strSeriesAndLabelDetail = [words objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"strSeriesAndLabelDetail is %@",strSeriesAndLabelDetail);

    NSArray *wordsToSeparateSeriesAndLabel = [strSeriesAndLabelDetail componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSLog(@"wordsSeriesLabel are %@",wordsToSeparateSeriesAndLabel);
    strLabelNumber = [wordsToSeparateSeriesAndLabel objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"strLabelNumber are %@",strLabelNumber);
    strSeriesNumber = [wordsToSeparateSeriesAndLabel objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"strSeriesNumber is %@",strSeriesNumber);
```

Current OutPut is:

```
words are (
    "series0001.0003",
    "Use the Sort-a-Cord app to read this code or visit www.sortacord.com to get your Sort-a-Cords."
)
strSeriesAndLabelDetail is series0001.0003
wordsSeriesLabel are (
    series0001,
    0003
)
strLabelNumber are 0003
strSeriesNumber is series0001
```

Can anybody help me out. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it:

```
NSString *stringToModify = @"series0110.0050";  
stringToModify = [stringToModify stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"series" withString:@""];
NSArray *array = [stringToModify componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Series %d %d", [[array objectAtIndex:0] integerValue], [[array objectAtIndex:1] integerValue]];
NSLog(@"%@",finalString);
```

Note that it maybe modified according to what you really want. I assumed that you got always "series" to look for.